# Downloaded Icons not showing in the tweaks in Ubuntu 21.10

Tags: gnome, icons, 20.10, gnome-tweaks

hi guys I have installed many icons from gnome-look.org/p/1080230 to try on my ubuntu 21.10 but none of them is showing in the gnome-tweak. it shows only the pre-installed icons and there is no option for new ones.

Steps I did when I download the icons from the gnome-look.org/p/1080230

1. Download the zip file
2. unzip it and copy it to the /usr/share/icons/
3. restarted the computer

but nothing helped I tried all the popular icons but none of them is working.

Comment: Link you are giving is not pointing to an icon set. Please remove your salutation: this here is not a user forum, but a Q&A site aimed to build quality questions and answers for future reference.

Comment: I would not mix up system icons and my own `mkdir $HOME/.icons/`  put the extractet icons there.

Answer (score 0):

You can copy the icons, but you need example `gnome-tweaks` to be able to choose which icons / themes ..etc you want on the system.

Try copy to `/home/user/.local/share/icons` or `/usr/share/icons` ,  but check that you have the correct content of the folders. Example

```
/usr/share/icons/Yaru$ ls
16x16     24x24       32x32     8x8           icon-theme.cache
16x16@2x  24x24@2x    32x32@2x  8x8@2x        index.theme
22x22     256x256     48x48     cursors       scalable
22x22@2x  256x256@2x  48x48@2x  cursor.theme  scalable-max-32
```

[image]

Comment: As written the answer makes no sense.